# Tempfile path returning int python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, temporary-files

I would like to know if there is a way to find the path of a temporary file without it returning an int (15 in my case). I would like to return a string (or an object in which I can then turn into one, please detail how) path is the path to the temp file (and the name of it). Example: /Users/FooBar/Python3.6/Modules/TempFile/Opus/THE_TEMP_FILE or something like that. I have already written a small .wav file to it and would like to get the path to get the playing time/duration of it using os .stat(). I want to use a temporary file because I am lazy and I do not want to do a lot of 'special' code for the four different operating systems I am trying to this program on. Here is my code:

```
import pygame, time, os, tempfile
import urllib.request as ur

pygame.init() # Initialize the pygame
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((1, 1)) # Sets display. Needed to play sound

sound = input('What sound should play: ') # Asks which sound
url = 'http://207.224.195.43:8000/' + sound # Gets server url
response = ur.urlopen(url) # Open url
data = response.read() # Create byte like object containing .wav code
f = tempfile.TemporaryFile() # Create TempFile
f.write(data) # Write .wav data gotten from server

f.seek(0) # Prepare to read it
soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound(f.read()) # Load sound to be played
f.seek(0) # Prepare to read it
statbuf = os.stat(f.name) # Gets stats from TempFile. Returns int, I want to fix that
mbytes = statbuf.st_size / 1024 # Gets 'not real' sound duration
soundObj.play() # Plays sounds
time.sleep(mbytes / 200) # Gets 'real' sound duration and waits
soundObj.stop() # Stops sounds once done
```

Let me know (comment) if you have any suggestions. I have looked at a few sites, one of which was on stack-overflow, one that you could mistake to be a duplicate of this question. It was about Django which as I understand is entirely different then python. Thanks for possibly answering this question. Remember, I am not looking for a confirmation on this is an issue, I already know that. Please give me a possible answer to the question as soon as you can.
Thanks!

-User 9311010

Comment: (1) Django is not entirely different than Python; it's a framework written in Python and used in Python code. (2) Just saying that you've looked other answers that might look like duplicates is not helpful. Tell us _which_ answers. Otherwise, someone may well incorrectly close your question as a dup of one of those, or give you the same answer that doesn't work for you, because nobody has any way of guessing that you already tried that answer.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of [`tempfile.TemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) is that there *is* no name for the file, if at all possible:

> … Under Unix, the directory entry for the file is either not created at all or is removed immediately after the file is created. Other platforms do not support this; your code should not rely on a temporary file created using this function having or not having a visible name in the file system.

If you want a temporary file with an accessible filename, use [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile):

> This function operates exactly as `TemporaryFile()` does, except that the file is guaranteed to have a visible name in the file system… That name can be retrieved from the name attribute of the returned file-like object.

---

However, I don't think you need a filename in the first place. Do you only want one so you have something to pass to `stat`? In Python 3.3+, you can pass a file object (like `f`) to `stat` instead of its name. In older versions, you can use `fstat` with the file's descriptor ([`fileno()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.fileno)).

Comment: I only want it to use to `os.stat()'. Could you give an example of using `tempfile.TemporaryFile()` or is that to much?

Comment: @user9311010 You just call `os.stat(f)`. Unless you're using Python 3.2, in which case you use `os.fstat(f.fileno())`.